# Binding ValidationRule from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding

I need to use the list 'lFx' from my ModelView

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource StyleTxtErr}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationGrp}"
         >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="sGrp" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:cDataGrpRule lFx="{Binding lFx}"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Actually, this code shows me this error at line '<local:cDataGrpRule ...'
A binding cannot be set to lFx, ...
A binding can only be set to DependencyProperty of a DependenxyObject

How can I initialize my ValidationRule Object with an object set in my ViewModel ?

Thanks in advance.
Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only bind to a dependency property, as the error message explains, yould create a wrapper class that derives from `DependencyObject` and exposes a dependency property.

You also need a proxy object that captures the current `DataContext`:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new BindingProxy();

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then you add a CLR property to the `ValidationRule` class that returns an instance of this wrapper type:

```
public class cDataGrpRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //your validation logic...
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }

    public Wrapper Wrapper { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty lFxProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("lFx", typeof(object), typeof(Wrapper));

    public object lFx
    {
        get { return GetValue(lFxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(lFxProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

You probably want to consider renaming the property to comply with the C# naming conventions.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
         Style="{StaticResource StyleTxtErr}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationGrp}">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </TextBox.Resources>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="sGrp" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:cDataGrpRule>
                    <local:cDataGrpRule.Wrapper>
                        <local:Wrapper lFx="{Binding Data.lFx, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                    </local:cDataGrpRule.Wrapper>
                </local:cDataGrpRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Please refer to the [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31422.wpf-passing-a-data-bound-value-to-a-validation-rule.aspx) for more information and a full example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I’m probably missing something
I've got this issue :

Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=lFx; DataItem=null; target element is 'cWrapperGrp' (HashCode=12036352); target property is 'lFx' (type 'List`1')

lFx is a List<cAppScriptImgGrp>

Comment: I forgot to add the `BindingProxy` in the example. See my edit and the linked article.

Comment: Many thank I never find this by myself.  
But WPF can be very verbose! 3 classes for one error message and for just one field !

Comment: It's easier to implement the validation in the view model.